# javascript class inheritance and visibility in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am using WebStorm as my IDE of choice and write a lot of JavaScript. Autocompletion is nice but in the case of JavaScript there are still... thins left to improve... This is at least what I experienced.

### For example

There are two classes, `A` and `B`:

```js
/**
 * This is Doc of class A
 * @constructor
 */
A = function () {
    this.name = "Class A";
    this.data = {
        foo: "Foo!",
        bar: "Bar!"
    };
};

/**
 * @inheritDoc A
 * @augments A
 * @constructor
 */
B = function () {
    A.call(this);

    // this works fine in the application
    // but is not registered by WebStorm / IntelliJ
    this.data.braz = "Braz!"
};

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

var a = new A();
var b = new B();
```

### My Probmem

In the IDE: when I start typing `a.` the autocompletion kicks in and displays **`data (A)`** and **`name (A)`**.

But when I type `b.` first of all it did not display the values, only after I added the `/** @augments A */`. WebStorm did not get it without it.

**But the main problem I have with it:** when I type `b.data.` **it won't offer me `braz (B)` as an option.**

Does anybody have experience with JavaScript, @JSDoc, WebStorm / IntelliJ and knows a solution?

---

What I **could** do is to write duplicate code and copy the `this.data` object from above and add the attributes I need.

What I **also could** do is to bring the content of `this.data` up to `this` directly. But that is not what I want.

Thanks in advance!